# Are Blue and Green the same character?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I'm confused: Blue is Red's rival from 'Red and Blue', and Green is the female trainer from 'Red and Green'. But in 'Pokemon Origins' - which is based on 'Red and Blue' - Blue is called Green. Then, who actually is Green? Are Blue and Green the same character?

Answer (score 7):

### It depends on the language

In the original Japanese language, the first generation games are Red and Green, and so the rival character of that generation is known as Green. The female protagonist from Fire Red and Leaf Green is known as Blue in Japan, with her name taken from [the game with the same name](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Blue_Version_(Japanese)) that was essentially a bug-fixed version of Red and Green.

Outside of Japan, there was no Green first generation game, and the games were sold as Red and Blue instead, so the rival character is known as Blue. The female protagonist is known as Green, taken from the Leaf Green game.

In all languages, the female protagonist from FRLG is also known as "Leaf" to helpfully avoid confusion. Any material depicting Red's rival is still known as Green in Japan but translated to Blue internationally, including in Pokémon Origins.

There is also a character called [Yellow](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Yellow_(Adventures)) but she is exclusive to the official manga.

Comment: I would say the female protagonist is based on [Green from the manga](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Green_(Adventures)), rather than "taken from the Leaf Green game".

Answer (score 1):

In Pokemon Origins both on the Bulbapedia and on Wikipedia there are separate voice actors for Blue, Red, and Green. With Blue being the main character.

On the Bulbapedia for the Manga it also says

> A native of Pallet Town, Green was kidnapped by a bird Pokémon when she was only five years old (six years prior to the first chapter), on the orders of the Masked Man. She was taken to a secret hideout and was trained with several other Masked Children. There, she met Silver and learned about Evolution. Eventually, they managed to escape into freedom. ***Green spent years traveling alone until she discovered she was from Pallet Town, where two boys her age had each received a starter Pokémon, a Pokédex, and set out on a journey.*** Frustrated, she broke into Professor Oak's laboratory and stole a Squirtle.

Those two boys are Red and Blue so Green is not Blue

Comment: This is about the manga, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part in the wiki. Fixed it.

Comment: The manga and games are separate canons with their own separate plots and backgrounds for characters. I don't believe this answer applies here.

Comment: I see..but in Pokemon Origins, Blue is called Green, he even wears a green shirt! Maybe, it was a dubbing mistake.